# Out of bounds when appending in Go slice

Tags: go, slice

In some cases when i == len(SliceA) i get a slice out of bounds error.

```
//filterIntersection removes points from two slices that have common points.
func filterIntersection(sliceA, sliceB *[]ds.Coord) {
    for i, a := range *sliceA {
        for j, b := range *sliceB {
            if a == b {
                (*sliceA) = append((*sliceA)[:i], (*sliceA)[i+1:]...) <--- error here
                (*sliceB) = append((*sliceB)[:j], (*sliceB)[j+1:]...)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if `i == len(SliceA)`, then `sliceA[i+1]` is out of bounds! It is not "in some cases" but in every case, and the same will happen for SliceB.

Consider breaking out of your loop if `i == len(SliceA)` or `j == len(SliceB)`.

Another solution would be to use a "regular" for loop: `for i := 0; i < len(SliceA); i++`

Comment: Yeah, ended up doing the second option. Stupid question.